# How exactly are exchange rates determined?

Tags: foreign-exchange, currency, economics

I was reading about how the exchange rates are fixed.  I understand that demand and supply decide the exchange rate but how exactly is it done and by whom?

For example, consider US and India.
(https://www.quora.com/Where-and-how-are-exchange-rates-determined)

When it comes to any currency, say US dollars, 
**Demand** for the currency exists due to the following reasons:

1. Import of goods and services from the USA
2. Direct purchases made in the USA by Indian tourists
3. Foreign investment by Indians in the USA
4. Speculative trading by Indians
5. Payment of international loans
6. Gifts and grants to the rest of the world

A currency(USD) is in **supply** due to the following reasons:

1. Export of Indian goods and services
2. Purchases by American tourists in India
3. FDI by Americans in India
4. Speculative trading by Americans in the Indian Rupee
5. Remittances from the USA

**Depending on which of the factors outweighs the other factors, the exchange rate is determined.**

Okay, but these are vague terms.  Who decides "Purchases by American tourists in India", how can anyone keep track of these things, and how exactly are these factors decided? **Is there a person sitting in an office somewhere who inputs some numbers in a formula and thus obtains the exchange rate?**.  I have a very limited understanding of economics so please bear with my noob question.

Comment: I'm reminded of an (in)famous quote from shortly after the end of WWII. A delegation of economists from the USSR had been allowed to visit the UK to help understand how to rebuild the Russian economy. On arriving in London they had a meeting with senior UK government economists. One of the first questions the Russians asked was, "Who is responsible for controlling the price of bread in London?" (And they had great difficulty understanding that the correct answer was "nobody").

Comment: @alephzero that is a question in a answer who is nobody. Why USSR need to ask British that question? I thought Soviet Union was a pillar stone for the west?

Comment: @alephzero Actually, the correct answer is "everybody".

Comment: @Nofel (In my layman understanding only!) the Soviet Union was a centrally planned communist economy. The government told the bakers how much money to sell bread for, and might've even told the bakers how much bread to make each day. In a more capitalist economy, the bakers can charge however much they want and the price eventually reaches an equilibrium due to constant adjustments - if they charge too much, nobody buys their bread, and if they charge too little, everyone wants their bread but they might not be able to bake it.

Comment: If you're a baker, the ideal price you should charge is the highest price that still means you sell all your bread. (If it's too high, you won't sell all of it, if it's too low, then you'll sell out early and you could've got more money). If there's not enough bread being made, people will see the high prices and go "oh, I could make a lot of money if I was a baker!" and they'll become bakers and make more bread, lowering the price again. That's my very quick explanation to you of how non-centrally-planned pricing should work.

Comment: The price of a currency *at an exchange shop* is simply set by the shop. No different from how WalMart sets the price of something. What do they base their price on? The actual *market price* of the currency. Note that the actual trading of, say, MSFT stock is on "the Nasdaq". The OP is simply asking "similar to how MSFT trades on 'the Nasdaq', where is it that currencies trade?" The answer is just the "InterbankMarket", which is a large international system (just like Nasdaq or Comex), which you don't hear about on the news much but is the trading platform for (massive amounts of) currencies.

Comment: Unrelated - just FYI, the UK had price controls after WW2, for many years.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rationing_in_the_United_Kingdom#Post-Second_World_War  (My dear Mother for example grew up in that era!)

Comment: @Fattie I was looking at that page a moment ago, looking for evidence of price-controls on bread, but -- while it talks about bread still being rationed up to 1948, and mentions fish prices being controlled from 1941, and the Milk Marketing Board controlling the price of milk _after_ the war, I cannot see any mention of them setting the price of bread. I'm not saying it _wasn't_ controlled, just that I couldn't find evidence that it was. (My mother _also_ grew up in that era, but unfortunately is no longer around to ask!)

Comment: Exchange rates are not fixed they are assigned.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

1. Currencies are indeed "actually" traded basically on what is called the **"Interbank Market"**

Here's a quick read on that:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_exchange_market

Let us compare and contrast!

- Stocks (like AAPL) are (as a rule) traded on the two or three huge "stock exchanges" such as "Nasdaq", which everyone has heard of.
- Commodities like gold and oil are (as a rule) traded on the two or three huge "commodities exchanges", such as "Nymex", "CME", etc, which many have heard of.
- And to your question, currencies generally are traded on the huge "Interbank Market" (as nicely described in that article).

This is a (fairly! - see below) free market. The price is determined exactly, each second, by buyers and sellers.

It is an OTC distributed system, **and very much an insider's market, which is broken in to tiers with the top tier being a small number of he world's huge banks.**

The literal trading amongst this group (that is to say, "the database, communications, etc") is handled by a shadowy concern called EBS (which indeed, "they" set up) (again, you need only turn to Wiki .. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_Broking_Services )

That is the only "real" price of a currency - the volume of the top tier is just overwhelmingly, astoundingly, large, and hence "is" the current price.

Just as Nasdaq continually reports the "actual" price of AAPL to the internet, and Nymex continually reports the "actual" price of gold and oil to the internet, the Interbank Market (on a literal technical level, basically "EBS") continually reports the "actual" price of EUR, AUD, etc to the internet.

## So in a sense the simple answer to your question ..

> "Where do currency prices come from?"

## is:

> "From a little-known behind-the-scenes technical platform called **EBS**. They handle the OTC trading of a **tight group of the biggest players** - the world's hugest financial institutions. They **trade freely** and openly in unbelievably large volumes, but each tier of access is **very much a "club"**. {Indeed, some see it as a **cartel**; there was indeed a **spectacularly large scandal** about this in recent times.} This is all in general known as **"the Interbank Market"**.

2. When you go to a local exchanger at the airport, they simply use that current rate, i.e. ultimately from the "Interbank Market" system.

Your question is astute...

When "you or I" change some money, the money changer retail shop on the street is *not* "trading", it's *not* a situation where two parties offer bids/asks. The shop simply offers a fixed price to buy or sell different currencies, and that fixed price is simply based on the current price seen on the "actual" market. (Exactly the same thing happen when you buy some ounces of *gold* from a retail gold dealer.)

To make a contrasting example - when you buy a house from some person, it's an actual trade with bids/asks by the parties involved, which will settle at some price.  And when you buy stocks (even 1 share) it's more or less an actual bids/asks situation.

Just to reiterate, this wiki article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_exchange_market pretty much fully explains the interbank market. Which is indeed the worldwide currency "exchange" - which is analogous to the Nasdaq "exchange" for stocks or Nymex "exchange" for gold and oil.

Many see this as a **cartel**; as it explains on wiki:

> "Unlike a stock market, the foreign exchange market is divided into levels of access. At the top is the interbank foreign exchange market, which is made up of the largest commercial banks and securities dealers..."

(indeed that precisely is where the price the OP is asking about comes from, via, on simply a technical level, the "EBS" platform which they set up and now use)

...which led to the spectacular ["Forex Scandal"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forex_scandal) of our times, and here's the [latest on that](https://www.ft.com/content/1b63dd84-c8bc-11e8-ba8f-ee390057b8c9).  Reading the articles on the zillion-dollar scandal, illuminates the overall scene.

(The only thing more "fixed" is the London gold fix, which is set each afternoon by five particular players in cahoots.)

Comment: " they literally just glance at the internet." actually i want to know who puts that rate on the internet in the first place? and how does he decides that rate?

Comment: I tried to sober up and clarify, @vikrant !  :)

Comment: thanks for the link, this really explains everything in detail, although i have to admit if i would have directly gone to the Wikipedia article i wouldn't have understood anything, but after reading the answers here i got a good foundation, and i am able to really understand the article. :)

Comment: Fantastic!  Score one for Chenin Blanc !

Comment: I hesitated to nitpick, because I think this completely answers the OP’s question. However, I wanted to clear a couple things up.  There are currently 13 US stock exchanges. Also, oil futures do trade on Nymex, but gold futures are on comex, both of which are now operated by cme group. Spot gold and oil trade otc, and in fact gold trades in essentially the same market as fx.  More seriously, I think that when one changes money at a retail shop, it typically is a bid/ask situation. They have a price at which thy will buy forex and a price at which they will sell.

Comment: wow so much information that’s so good but I am lost after few lines.

Comment: @Callus They do have two separate prices, but I think they mean that you don't get to bid or ask whatever price you want. Your options are take it or leave it, much like any other retail shop.

Comment: Hi @Callus !  Sure, they have a (fixed, stated) buy price and a (fixed, stated) sell price.  (Very simply, exactly like buying something at a WalMart.)  What I meant was it is not a "negotiation".  In contrast, when for example you purchase a car from me, you make bids, I make asks, etc and we finally settle on a price.  That's all I meant there!.

Comment: Also yes when I said "commodities trading" that is futures contracts.  But not relevant to the OP here!

Comment: There's no "Interbank Market", analogous to the Nasdaq or NYMEX exchanges.  The "interbank market" (notice the lack of capitalization) isn't a single centralized exchange like Nasdaq or NYMEX. As Wikipedia says: "There is no unified or centrally cleared market for the majority of trades, and there is very little cross-border regulation. Due to the over-the-counter (OTC) nature of currency markets, there are rather a number of interconnected marketplaces, where different currencies instruments are traded." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_exchange_market#Trading_characteristics

Comment: It's not actually that different for the common person looking to change some money.  While for most of us who only need a small amount of currency convenience trumps price, if you call around to the various organizations in your area that offer money-changing services you'll often find that the prices can have a fair amount of variation and wildly different fee schedules.  So it is indeed still a market with prices determined by the buyers and sellers, it's just a smaller one with fewer participants.

Comment: hi @RossRidge !  (an OTC maket is just a market)  when you lookup "the" current reported currency price of a currency you're seeing the price on the (tier one) interbank market; further the actual London fix comes from that.

Comment: I'm not sure what point trying to make, but there's no single "Interbank Market" entity in London that's reporting currency prices that's analogous to how there's a single Nasdaq Stock Market in New York that reports the prices of stocks listed that exchange. While the Nasdaq is the central market for a majority of trades in the most of the stocks listed on it, there's no single market in London or anywhere else where a majority of currency trades happen, as the Wikipedia article you linked says and I quoted above.

Comment: The price you see reported as "the" price of a particular currency is the current price the tier 1 group of interbank players (I believe they use the EBS system).  (Similarly with stocks, there's also a "distributed, non-central" OTC market, and you can see those OTC prices reported.)

Comment: Ah, actually it's mentioned right in that article:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_Broking_Services .. *"Major trading exchanges include Electronic Broking Services (EBS) and Thomson Reuters Dealing, while major banks also offer trading systems. A joint venture of the Chicago Mercantile Exchange and Reuters, called Fxmarketspace opened in 2007 and aspired but failed to the role of a central market clearing mechanism..."*

Comment: Here .. this is exactly what we're both saying .. *"There is no unified or centrally cleared market for the majority of trades, and there is very little cross-border regulation. Due to the over-the-counter (OTC) nature of currency markets, there are rather a number of interconnected marketplaces, where different currencies instruments are traded. [ ... ] In practice, the rates are quite close due to arbitrage. Due to London's dominance in the market, a particular currency's quoted price is usually the London market price..."*  Which happens on EBS. Then -> data providers -> the internet

Answer (score 12):

Here's a very simple way to determine the exchange rate between dollars and euros, assuming you have a few dollars:

1. Go from place to place and ask them how many euros they'll give you for your dollars. Accept the best offer you get.
2. Go from place to place and ask people how many dollars they'll give you for your euros. Accept the best offer you get.
3. If you made a profit, go back to step 1.
4. Average the two exchange rates you got the last time you executed steps 1 and 2.
5. This is the exchange rate between dollars and euros.

As there are markets that permit people to offer and accept trades between currencies all over the world, this process is constantly going on in large amounts in numerous places with every currency known to man. Currencies worth a total of approximately $5 trillion per day are traded in this way. From this stream of trades, the exchange rates can readily be determined.

All of the factors listed in the question affect what trades people are willing to make. But the rate is determined from the trades people actually make. The same is true with the price of a car. The cost of steel and the cost of labor go into the price of a car. But when you want to know the price of a car, what you want to know is what price people are actually buying and selling cars for, and you determine this by looking at car sales.

Answer (score 11):

No one applies the factors to calculate an exchange rate (for freely floating currencies) — it’s not calculated at all, but determined from what actually happens in the market. People who want to buy currency A with currency B bid on how much of currency B they are prepared to give in order to get currency A. Similarly, people who want to buy currency B with currency A also bid. When the bids match up, a transaction happens, and that is the exchange rate, until the next transaction. Since in practice the rate won’t vary very much from minute to minute for actively traded currencies, places that exchange small amounts of cash for consumers will set a rate for the day rather than checking the current rate every time they do a transaction.

Comment: "places that exchange small amounts of cash for consumers" , they are the banks? and how do they find out the exchange rate. i understand the process of bidding you explained, but if these places are setting the exchange rates in advance, how do they determine it even before the bidding has started?

Comment: @vikrant Anyone can do consumer currency exchange (in principle, depending on local laws). Got $10 in cash left over from a US trip? You can sell them to a friend for your local currency. Congratulations, you’re a bureau de change.

Comment: if i sell my $10 to a friend and no one knows about it, how am i deciding the exchange rate? how can we keep track of who is selling to whom at what price?

Comment: @vikrant You can decide the exchange rate in any way that is mutually acceptable to you and your friend. But the obvious solution would be to look up the current market exchange rate on the Internet, which is basically what real bureaux de change do.

Comment: yes we can decide the rate mutually acceptable to us, but how is the actual exchange rate on the internet to which everyone agrees upon is decided? you mentioned in your answer that "places that exchange small amounts of cash for consumers will set a rate for the day", what are those places and how do they figure out the rate even before the bidding process?

Comment: My answer explains how it’s set. It’s the price of the last transaction on the actual currency markets, which do not include transactions between you and your friend, your local bank or a bureau de change. Small places like that just take the overnight rate from the actual markets and use it as their exchange rate for the day.

Comment: " It’s the price of the last transaction on the actual currency markets". i understand, so each country decides their exchange rate based on the last transaction? or is there a central authority to do that? for eg, in case of United States, which institution is responsible for deciding it? sorry if i am asking stupid question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85912/discussion-between-mike-scott-and-vikrant).

Comment: @vikrant It doesn’t need a central authority to keep the price the same across all markets, arbitrageurs do that. If one market has a lower price for dollars than another, then they instantly buy dollars in the cheaper market and sell them in the more expensive one. That keeps the prices the same.

Comment: ok, so the arbitrageurs are responsible to keep the price of currencies same across all markets. but i still want to know for eg in United States which are the places that decide the currency rate based on the last transaction?

Comment: @vikrant The exchange rate is what people actually pay. You want $1 for an apple, and Mary wants $0.80 for an apple, and I can't find a better deal, so I give Mary $0.80 and get my apple. The exchange rate for apples is now $0.80 per apple. Only nobody cares about the exchange rate of one apple.

Comment: Deutsche Bank is offering 20 billion euros for 18 billion pounds, Barclay's is offering 20 billion euros for 17 billion pounds, Lloyd's can't find a better deal so they accept Barclay's offer and that's now the exchange rate. People actually care about *that* exchange rate since it's a lot of money.

Comment: @vikrant To make a very crude analogy, asking how a country determines its exchange rate would be like asking how the club determines how hot you have to be to go home with someone. And the answer is that they don't. It's determined by all the interactions between all the people involved, averaging out to some sort of equilibrium price (or level of attractiveness).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85965/discussion-on-answer-by-mike-scott-how-exactly-are-exchange-rates-determined).

Answer (score 2):

There are two things going on here.

First, how "the price" is determined.  There are actual real-time buying and selling of currency and future promises to deliver currency going on.  This is called the ForEX market, for "Foreign Exchange market".

This market is relatively high volume and stable for most major currencies.  People make money on the market mostly through highly leveraged positions, where they put up X dollars, borrow 10X dollars, and use that to speculate.  As long as they are buying a major currency, the person lending them money figures they can recoup their money before it drops by a factor of 10.

The last buy/sell on this market (or averages between them) is the "rate of exchange" that you can find on the internet.

You are probably not buying on this market.  Possibly you are going to some kiosk somewhere and paying money for some other currency.

These kiosks peg their rate to that market.  They have actual bills there, and bank accounts.  They take the rate, add a premium on it, and offer to exchange money based on that.  They are betting that the rate of exchange won't change so fast that they'll lose money on restoking their cash, and that they'll make a healthy profit on the premium.

So if the EURO is 1.1 USD, at the Kiosk they might sell EURO for 1.15 USD and buy USD for 0.85 EURO.  That 5% is their profit margin.

Credit cards and banks will offer the same thing, electronically; they'll convert your electronic USD for electronic Rupees.  The price they'll offer is based off ForEX markets, plus a premium.  They might even make a trade of the ForEX market to buy/sell the expected currency of each type that they need that day.  Or they might initially operate on credit (where they borrow the Rupees you buy), then clear it later (at the end of day), again trusting that their premium will cover any currency flux.

---

Now the reason why people talk about sources of Demand and Supply is that if there is a whole pile of Demand for Rupees and not much for USD, over time the price will tend to move.  This is because there isn't an infinite amount of Rupees and USD up for sale.  If demand for Rupees grows, people start having problems getting the Rupees they need.  Companies that stock exchange kiosks with money buy out the "lowest offer" Rupees, and buy from  higher offer ones.  Same goes for Banks buying Rupees that they offer to their customers on their credit cards, or when clearing their debts.

The price of Rupees goes up, USD goes down, and quickly people reconsider buying some good from India, or liquidate some Indian bonds and move it to the US.  This provides a force pushing the price the other way, as the supply of Rupees on the market increases and USD goes down.